# Show that $(K,d)$ is a complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

$K=[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$, so $K$ is an infinite cube existing of all rows $(x_n)$, and for $n\geq1$, $d(x,y)=\sum{2^{-n}|x_n-y_n|}$, with $x=(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ and $y=(y_n)_{n\geq1}$.

I need to show that $(K,d)$ is a complete metric space. I already did something with showing that a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. But apparently this is not the way to do it, or at least not enough. Because you have rows in rows.

Can someone help which step to take?

Comment: Take a Cauchy sequence $\bigl(x^{(k)}\bigr)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $K$. Show that each component sequence $\bigl(x^{(k)}_n\bigr)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $[0,1]$. Consider the pointwise limit, and show that $x^{(k)}$ converges to that.

Comment: So I have to do something with choosing a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for the component $n$ of the sequence $\bigl(x_n^{(k)}\bigr)_{k\in \mathbb{N}} $ and then show that for a $\epsilon\geq0$. take a certain $N$: for all $n,m \geq N$ I need to show that $d(x,y)=\sum{2^{-n}|x_{n}^n-y_{n}^m|}<\epsilon$. How do i show that this is the case?

Comment: You're using $n$ for two different things there, better use $k$ for the sequence index if you use $n$ for the component. From what relation between $d(x^{(k)}, x^{(m)})$ and $\lvert x^{(k)}_n - x^{(m)}_n\rvert$ can you deduce that $\bigl(x^{(k)}_n\bigr)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: @DanielFischer I had the same question as above. Could you perhaps give a partial solution to this problem?

Comment: @model_checker A _partial_ solution is going to be really difficult, there are not many reasonable steps between a hint and a full solution here. Have you a particular problem with trying to show the completeness?

Comment: @DanielFischer I was following your hint and wanted to show that $(x^{(k)}_n)$ is Cauchy. For this, we want to show that $|x^{(k)}_i- x^{(k)}_j|$ goes to $0.$ I was trying to use triangle inequality here like this $|x^{(k)}_i - x^{(k)}_j|\leq |x^{(k)}_i - x^{(m)}_i| + |x^{(m)}_i - x^{(m)}_j| + |x^{(m)}_j - x^{(k)}_j|$ but its not quite helpful.

Comment: @model_checker The subscript $n$ is fixed, the superscript $(k)$ varies. The thing to show is that for sufficiently large $k,m$ you have $\lvert x^{(k)}_n - x^{(m)}_n\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon$. [And that for every $n$.] To obtain that, you need to use a relation between $\lvert x_n - y_n\rvert$ and $d(x,y)$ for $x,y \in K$ (and apply that relation to $x^{(k)}$ and $x^{(m)}$ in place of $x$ and $y$), and the assumption that $\bigl(x^{(k)}\bigr)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $K$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I can see that $d(x,y) \leq \max{|x_n-y_n|},$ but I am not sure what relation you have in mind.

Comment: @model_checker Let's take a specific $n$, say $n = 23$. Given $d(x,y)$, what is the most precise thing you can deduce about $\lvert x_{23} - y_{23}\rvert$?

Comment: @DanielFischer One can say that $$\frac{|x_{23}-y_{23}|}{2^{23}} < d(x,y) \leq 2.$$ So

Comment: @model_checker Exactly, or by rearranging $\lvert x_{23} - y_{23}\rvert \leqslant 2^{23}\cdot d(x,y)$. And you can of course replace the $23$ everywhere with a generic $n$. So $\lvert x^{(k)}_n - x^{(m)}_n\rvert \leqslant 2^n\cdot d(x^{(k)},x^{(m)})$ for all $k,m,n$. Now fix $n$ and use the assumption that $\bigl(x^{(k)}\bigr)$ is Cauchy to deduce that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $M_{n,\varepsilon}$ such that $\lvert x^{(k)}_n - x^{(m)}_n\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon$ for all $k, m \geqslant M_{n,\varepsilon}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh I see so first we assumed that $(x^{(k)})$ was Cauchy with respect to $d$. Then using your argument we showed that it is Cauchy with respect to the usual metric in $\mathbb{R}.$ This means that it is convergent to a sequence $x = (x^{1}, x^{2},\cdots, $ where each of them must lie in $[0,1].$ Right?

Comment: @model_checker $\bigl(x^{(k)}\bigr)$ is a sequence in $K$, the components $\bigl(x^{(k)}_n\bigr)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ are sequences in $[0,1]$, which by the argument above are Cauchy sequences, hence convergent. And thus we have a pointwise limit $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$, where $$x_n = \lim_{k \to \infty} x^{(k)}_n$$ for every $n$. This $x$ belongs to $K$ of course, and it remains to show that it is the $d$-limit of $\bigl(x^{(k)}\bigr)$.